# In this example why do they hash a randomly generated piece of salt before hashing it with the password?

Tags: passwords, hash, php, blowfish

From [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/), in the code `return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);` what is the point of taking the sha1 value? It is appended to the password and together they are hashed using Blowfish.  Why not just append the randomly generated number?

```
class PassHash {  
    // blowfish  
    private static $algo = '$2a';  
    // cost parameter  
    private static $cost = '$10';  
    // mainly for internal use  
    public static function unique_salt() {  
        return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);  
    }  
    // this will be used to generate a hash  
    public static function hash($password) {  
        return crypt($password,  
                    self::$algo .  
                    self::$cost .  
                    '$' . self::unique_salt());  
    }  
    // this will be used to compare a password against a hash  
    public static function check_password($hash, $password) {  
        $full_salt = substr($hash, 0, 29);  
        $new_hash = crypt($password, $full_salt);  
        return ($hash == $new_hash);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Short answer: Because they don't know what they're doing. It has no beneficial effect what-so-ever.

Comment: if you're using php 5.5 use the built in functions, else use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat (requires PHP >= 5.3.7) which offers the same API. These are designed and written by somebody who knows what he's doing.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I installed the package but am confused because I [get a different hash value for the same input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265967/hash-value-always-different-on-same-input). Is this expected? If yes how do I check the password next time the user wants to log in?

Comment: your unique_salt() sucks

Comment: Well that was quite the conundrum.

Comment: @Celeritas The salt is indeed a new (pseudo)random number every time it is generated. It should be generated only once per password and stored in clear along with the password.

Comment: @Celeritas - Yes, each password gets it's own salt, therefore equal passwords get different hash-values. To check if the password matches the hash-value, you use the function `password_verify()` instead, here you can find an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14274045/575765).

Comment: How does `password_verify()` work when the salt used is random and not stored anywhere? Does the first 6 characters in the hash value (e.g. $2y$11$) determine the salt that was being used?

Comment: @Celeritas - The part `2y` is the algorithm BCrypt, the part `11` is the cost factor and the next 22 characters are the salt. The rest after the salt is the actual hash-value. The whole string can be stored in the database, and when you verify the password these parameters are extracted from the stored hash-value to hash the entered password. Have a look at the bottom of this [page](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/hash_bcrypt.php) for an example.

Comment: @martinstoeckli thanks but that's not what I was asking. I'm asking how `password_verify()` works since `password_hash()` gives different output for the same input?

Comment: @Celeritas - What i tried to explain is, that the salt is part of the generated hash-value. The `password_verify()` gets the entered password and the stored hash-value from the database, and can extract the salt from the stored hash-value. Then it calculates the hash of the entered password, with the same salt it used to calculate the stored hash-value. Now it can compare the hash-values, because they are based on the same salt.

Comment: @martinstoeckli but how does `password_verify()` extract the salt from the saved hash value when a random salt was used to generate it?

Comment: @Celeritas - The stored salt is **plain text**, it is not hashed itself. You can just look for the signature `$2y$10$` and the next 22 characters **are** the used salt, you can reuse it to calculate the new hash. In contrast to `password_hash()`, the function `password_verify()` does **not** create it's own salt, it uses the extracted salt from the stored hash-value.

Comment: @martinstoeckli ok I get it now, I thought the remainder of the entire hash after the last $ was only 22 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do this hashing out of a mixture of insecurity and shamanism.

The hashing has no value for actual security. Their salting is **bad** because `mt_rand()` is not sufficient to ensure uniqueness (good salts should strive to be unique, and random salts are a good way to get unique values with high probability, but it requires the use of a *good* random generator, in a *sufficiently large* space of value; and [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) fails at both). Hashing the output of `mt_rand()` with SHA-1 gives the *impression* that the salt is more random than it really is; the developers must have the warm fuzzy feeling that things are safer since they "look random" to their human eyes.

Also, sprinkling hash function invocations on a given piece of code is a way to propitiate the Spirits of Cryptography. It is well-known that crypto deities look favourably upon those who use them a lot (or so many developers believe, apparently).

Answer (score 0):

(Expanded to incorporate feedback from CodesInChaos)

To answer the "why" which is your question, i.e. in the general case of salt generation:

A salt is usually visible, it's not a secret.
Simply using the random value *might* reveal some internal state information of the random number generator. A one-way hashing function hides that.

It is a poor substitute for a cryptographically secure PRNG. Such a PRNG will use one or more cryptographically secure hashed internally.

In this specific case it adds no value due to the low entropy output of PHP's mt_rand() (31 bits), and at worst may mislead.
See also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618836/how-if-at-all-does-a-predictable-random-number-generator-get-more-secure-after

Comment: Due to the small amount of values `mt_rand` can return, undoing that SHA-1 hash is trivial. => no gain at all.

Comment: Yes that is true with PHP's mt_rand(), so it's a spectacularly poor choice for selecting a salt. I believe that the principle is still correct however.

Comment: If seeing a value from the RNG reveals anything useful about the RNG, the RNG is badly broken and must not be used anywhere near crypto (it may still be ok for numerical simulations).